# react-native & firebase: request with a condition where in the mappage

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Example of a json in my database

[image]

request

```
  firestore()
        .collection(COLLECTION)
        .where("types", ">=", 'lDQJJnsq2osTIWCPLMRg')
        .get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
            const arr = []
            querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
                const data = documentSnapshot.data()
                const el = {id: documentSnapshot.id, ...data}
                arr.push(el)
            })
            resolve(arr)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('err ', err )
            reject()
        });
```

1. Filer my collection if the property types containt a id specific
   I don't find how I add a condition 'where' in the mappage ('types')
   In my logic, If types containt my id ("lDQJJnsq2osTIWCPLMRg") return this object.
2. Maybe for mobile, it's better to make a call with pagination, I found the method 'startAt' can help for pagination.  It's correct ?

I begin with react-native & firebase, so thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For paginating queries you need to use query cursors:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors

1. use firestore.query to order your collection with orderBy
2. use startAfter and limit to implement the pagination

Comment: thanks for the pagination , 
you have a answer for the bullet point 1 ? 
Thanks

Comment: Can you rephrase your first question? I don't fully understand what you are asking